# How can I get around a torrent block imposed by the network admin?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I'm interested to know if there is a 'hack' that would allow peer-to-peer traffic, which I'm guessing the admin has blocked, because I can download torrent files and when they open in my client I can't get connected to the trackers and/or peers. See below.

[image]

Comment: Any answer to this, based on what's in the question, will necessarily be purely speculative. If you have a valid case for Bittorrent being allowed, make that case to your network administrator. If you don't have a valid case for using Bittorrent, then you shouldn't be trying to bypass the block which was probably set up for a reason.

Comment: You may follow these steps https://torrentfreak.com/bittorrent-over-ssh-071014/ Byepassing a Firewall rule is not recommended. Its been blocked for a purpose.

Comment: To add to @MichaelKjörling : The reason you can download torrent files is because they are hosted by standard HTTP - as they are available to download from torrent websites. It's only when your torrent client tries to connect to the peer network that different ports are then used.

Comment: Corporate networks are generally off topic here and there are several side reasons why we would not support your circumvention of their security features. If you like your job then I would recommend not risking it for the latest episodes of your favourite TV program as they almost certainly will be able to trace you and you could well be disciplined for violating company policy. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9252/what-is-the-definition-of-corporate-it-support

Comment: If you actually *need* bittorrent for your job then the only person who can help you is your IT guy.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm interested to know if there is a 'hack' that would allow peer-to-peer traffic,

There is a work around:

Use online cloud services ( for eg: zbigz, quick-torrent ) to download the data intended to be downloaded by torrent or magnet file to their cloud servers and then download it to your machine using your browser or download manager client. So now no one is hurt and you're not breaking any law or policy...

Downsides are limited hosting space and bandwidth for free users.